# Pandas replace dataframe values based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a master dataframe, df:

```
Colour Item   Price
Blue   Car     40
Red   Car     30
Green  Truck   50
Green  Bike    30
```

I then have a price correction dataframe, df_pc:

```
Colour Item   Price
Red   Car     60
Green  Bike    70
```

I want to say if there is a match on Colour and Item in the price correction dataframe, then replace the price in the master df. so the expected output is;

```
Colour Item   Price
Blue   Car     60
Red   Car     30
Green  Truck   50
Green  Bike    70
```

I can't find a way of doing this currently

Comment: First, think about what should happen, if there's more than one match. Assuming there's not, you can merge both dataframes on the key Colour/Item and then fill the blanks in the merged dataframe column with values from the first dataframe. Please post a working code example generating your dataframes if you need exact code help.

Comment: ok thanks, yes no duplicates. would you say thats the best way of doing it?

Comment: there's `df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', subset=['Colour', 'Item']) ` with parameters on what to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) for filter out no matched rows and then [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['Colour','Item'])
df_pc = df_pc.set_index(['Colour','Item'])

df_pc = df_pc[df_pc.index.isin(df.index)]
df = df_pc.combine_first(df).reset_index()
print (df)
  Colour   Item  Price
0   Blue    Car   40.0
1  Green   Bike   70.0
2  Green  Truck   50.0
3    Red    Car   60.0
```

Another data test:

```
print (df_pc)
   Colour  Item  Price
0     Red   Car     60
1  Orange  Bike     70 <- not matched row

df = df.set_index(['Colour','Item'])
df_pc = df_pc.set_index(['Colour','Item'])
df_pc = df_pc[df_pc.index.isin(df.index)]
df = df_pc.combine_first(df).reset_index()
print (df)
  Colour   Item  Price
0   Blue    Car   40.0
1  Green   Bike   30.0
2  Green  Truck   50.0
3    Red    Car   60.0
```

Comment: thanks @jezrael. this is great. May I just check, if there is an unnecessary row in the df_pc, that is then just ignored (and not added to master in anyway)?

Comment: ah I see, thats what your edit is doing. thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

here is a way using `combine_first()`:

```
df_pc.set_index(['Colour','Item']).combine_first(
       df.set_index(['Colour','Item'])).reset_index()
```

---

```
  Colour   Item  Price
0   Blue    Car   40.0
1  Green   Bike   70.0
2  Green  Truck   50.0
3    Red    Car   60.0
```

EDIT:
If you want only matching items, we can also use merge with fillna:

```
print(df_pc)

  Colour  Item  Price
0     Red   Car     60
1  Orange  Bike     70 #changed row not matching

(df.merge(df_pc, on = ['Colour','Item'],how='left',suffixes=('_x',''))
   .assign(Price=lambda x:x['Price'].fillna(x['Price_x'])).reindex(df.columns,axis=1))
```

---

```
  Colour   Item  Price
0   Blue    Car   40.0
1    Red    Car   60.0
2  Green  Truck   50.0
3  Green   Bike   30.0
```